# Filtering against lastModifiedDate throwing a 501 error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a list of JSON objects SharePoint document drive retrieved using Microsoft Graph. I'm trying append a `?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge 2019-10-01T20:42:15Z` but it is returning a `501` error.

I've tried toying around with many different variations to no success, strangely, when I switch the `filter` to `select` it works, so not really sure what the issue is?

```
{
  "context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('a')/drives('b')/items('c')/children",
  "value": [
    {
      "etag": "\"{id},x\"",
      "lastModifiedDateTime": "2019-10-01T20:42:15Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding single quotes around the date value? ?$filter=lastModifiedDateTime ge '2019-10-01T20:42:15Z'

Comment: @baywet i did indeed! marc has given the answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph doesn't support filtering a `DriveItem` collection. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters):

> This method supports the $expand, $select, $skipToken, $top and $orderby OData query parameters to customize the response.

Comment: Thanks Marc, I guess this is not possible via the graph api then? thanks for your help!

Comment: That is _mostly_ true. What you can (and should) use are Delta Queries. These return anything that has changed since the previous query.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-delta?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: - ah that looks v. interesting. I'm assuming this can be implemented with logic-apps?

Comment: To be honest, I've never tried. That said, I expect it would work. You do need to store the delta token returned after each pass but otherwise its basically identical to a normal Graph call.